# How to make setTextSize work on Android 8.0?

Tags: java, android, android-8.0-oreo

I have a function that uses setTextSize to increase or decrease the font size as the user presses a button in the application, this function works perfectly in Android 7.0, however, in Android 8.0 it simply stopped working, I did not make any changes in the code.
Follow code:

```
        mMais.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mTamanho = mTamanho + 10;
                mNome.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, mTamanho);
            }
        });        
        mMenos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mTamanho = mTamanho - 10;
                mNome.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, mTamanho);
            }
        });
```

Console Debug:

[image: Console Debug]

LogCat and Event Log:

[image: LogCat and Event Log]

The commands to increase and decrease the font are changed in the Debug Console, the problem is that on the screen the text is not being rendered, keeping static

Increase - Decrease :

[image: Increase - Decrease]

Comment: Ok, sorry for that.

Comment: any exception in logcat ?

Comment: @SRBbans logcat don't show nothing, Logcat does not show anything, I updated the question the images Console Debut, Log Cat and Event Log.
When I tap the buttons to increase or decrease the text, it appears in the Debug Console "playSoundEffect effectType: 0"

Comment: check this  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:autoSizeTextType. set textsize do not work when 
      set  android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"